# Как разобрать строку в XSLT преобразовании

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Есть XML документ и необходимо произвести его XSLT преобразовании.
Беда в том, что строка должна быть разобрана по ячейкам таблицы - одна буква в одной ячейке, чтобы образовывать подобие печатной формы
то есть

```
<Документ КНД="1111053" ДатаДок="16.01.2012" КодНО="7601">
```

должно выглядеть примерно так

```
<tr>
<td>КНД</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25781731/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За основу взят этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25781731/5045688).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Документ">
    <tr>
      <td>КНД</td>
      <xsl:call-template name="parseString">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@КНД"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="parseString">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>

    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1, 1)"/>
    </td>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($text) > 1">
      <xsl:call-template name="parseString">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 2, string-length($text) - 1)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```